# Use single create content flow to create many nodes

Tags: nodes, media, files

I am building a site for a charity. Amongst other things, the site lists a number of upcoming events. I have created a custom content type for these events (with fields like `title`, `body`, `date`, `location`). I want users to be able to upload photographs taken at these events, and am not sure what is the best way to do it.

I was going to create a new content type called something like *Event Photographs*, and by using a module like [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) I could require the users to select an event.

But our users will probably have many photographs to upload for each event.

**Is it possible for my users to follow a single add node / create content flow but upload many photographs at once to create many nodes?**

An alternative is to have a single node, with multiple fields, but then I lose the benefits of each photo being its own node (e.g. commenting).

Answer (score 0):

[Bulk File Nodes](https://drupal.org/project/bulk_file_nodes) is the solution for you to upload many files/pictures and create a node of it. Rest depends on your Logic how you implement it.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get Bulk File Nodes to work on [simplytest.me](http://simplytest.me/project/bulk_file_nodes/7.x-1.0), and I got the same result locally. The Create New pop/layer is empty.